# Merge .txt files using paste - need more columns

Tags: terminal, paste

I am trying to merge 600 txt files with 1 column and 372 rows of numeric values into one txt file with a separate column for each of the files (so 600 columns)

I've tried to use the paste command in terminal, and it merged all my files, but there was only 8 columns.

Is there a way to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Is this a programming problem/question? Please have a look at some helpful tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - asking a good question improves your chances of getting an answer. 
Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). 
And more importantly, please read the Stack Overflow question checklist.

Comment: What would be the separator between columns? Are you looking to get a .csv file as the final result because .txt files are not "column friendly"? You don't really have columns in a text file, it's not Excel. What is the purpose, what are you looking to do with the file next?